# How to choose the cut-off frequency for removing the DC components

Tags: highpass-filter

I'm trying to remove the DC components from a signal in a static situation (there is no movement), so I'm using a high pass filter with a cut-off frequency of 0.1 Hz (since the DC components happen at 0 Hz). Is this true, and if not how to choose the correct cut-off frequency?

Comment: Just a nit, but 0.1Hz, presumably?  Edit that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a cutoff frequency of 0.1Hz -- or any other arbitrary choice -- will work depends on what you're doing.

A framework for thinking about this is to ask yourself if the error between what you want to measure and what's coming out of your filter is small enough for the signal to be "good", and whether that happens soon enough after start-up.

Assuming you're using a first-order highpass filter -- i.e. one that satisfies the difference equation
$$\begin{align}
x_k &= \alpha \left( u_k - x_{k-1} \right) \\
y_k &= u_k - x_k
\end{align}, \tag 1$$

where $x_k$ is an internal variable (it's a low-pass filtering of $u_k$), $u_k$ is your input, and $y_k$ is your output, then for an $\alpha$ selected for a bandwidth of 0.1Hz, the time constant of the filter will be about 1.6 seconds.  That means that the error between the output and what you want will go as $y_{DC} e^{-\frac{t}{1.6 \mathrm s}}$, where $y_{DC}$ is the offset you're trying to filter out and $t$ is the time after startup.

So -- do the math!  Does the filter settle out fast enough to work?  If so, you're done.